# quotes around filename in backticks not being recognized in resque task, but works in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I have a resque task to unzip a file. This task works perfectly when there are no spaces in the absolute filename; however, it is failing when there is a space in the name. I have added quotes around the filename in the backticks (see below), but this does not seem to make a difference in the resque task. What is even stranger is that I can run the exact command in the console, and it works perfectly.

Here is my code. In the below f.filename = 'russell/artificial-proto-aips/Batch 1/rbrl-999-er-000001_bag.61440.tar.bz2':

```
f = JobFile.find(id)
output = `tar xjf "#{File.join( '/', 'storage', f.filename )}" -C /working 2>&1`
```

Running in console:

```
2.3.0 :009 > output = `tar xjf "#{File.join( '/', 'storage', f.filename )}" -C /working 2>&1`
 => ""
```

Contents of output after running the resque task:

```
tar (child): /storage/russell/artificial-proto-aips/Batch: Cannot open: No such file or directory\ntar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now\ntar: Child returned status 2\ntar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now\n
```

I must admit, I am quite baffled by this behavior, but I don't want to tell my users not to use spaces in the directory names (as much as I would like to).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue though. Backticks call `/bin/sh`, so my bash style commands were failing. Updating `/bin/sh` to point to `/bin/bash` fixed it right up.